# Is it possible to control headphone jack's output voltage on Android?

Tags: android, controls, headphones

I am playing with some sensors which are made to be used on cell phone's headphone jack. Using sensors on iPhone or specific Android phones (Galaxy III for example) is no problem, but on other Android phones (for example Nexus S, Nexus, ...) output voltage is to low...

Is it by any chance possible to control output voltage using software solution?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the voltage linear to the volume? `U = R I`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from "raising the volume" (which will also raise the amps on the audio jack), there is no easy software-based solution to raise the voltage of the audio jacks on a mobile phone. This would require you to root the device and make changes to the audio drivers.